# Apps not updating

Tags: updates

No matter what I do, my apps due for update are going on downloading. The Notification bar shows paused. I have factory reset my play store, it worked the last time, but not now.

Answer (score 0):

So this may be a silly response, but have you tried turning off and back on your phone? It usually kicks things like that into shape, in addition you could try turning on and off airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

Things that could cause this:

1. Time/date not correct on your phone
2. You have changed the password of the email address associated with your Play Store
3. You are out of space on your phone
4. Your Google Apps framework needs to be updated